# Github Pages Deployment deploys a blank page

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, github-pages

My website is displaying a blank page. When I inspect element, it says "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.", but I know that my JS is already enabled on my browser.

I followed these instructions to deploy the project: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

Here is the repository: https://github.com/eric-mxrtin/weather-app-react

Here is the link to the site: https://eric-mxrtin.github.io/weather-app-react/?lang=en

Note: My project runs fine on local host.